# Problema com ajax e cURL para receber o valor do mysql e retornar para o html

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html5, libcurl

gente estou com um problema usando html, ajax, cURL e mysql. a função é simples uma pagina html onde vai receber um nome e vai enviar por ajax para o cURL que vai acessar o php que conecta ao mysql e pega 2 coluna da tabela e retorna o valor para uma tabela criada no html.

**código html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
     <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>
    CONSULTA DE CLIENTE
    </title>
    </head>
      body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form action="" id="form1" method="post" name="busca" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type="text" name="txt_nome" id="nome"/>
  <input type="submit" name="seach" value="BUSCAR" />
</form>
<div class="response">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      $('#form1').submit(function(e){
          var nome = $('#nome').val();
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
              url: 'clientes_curl.php',
              type: 'POST',
              datatype: 'JSON',
              data: {
                cliente_nome:$('#nome').val()
              },
              success: function(data){
                alert(data.cliente_nome);
                var html='<table border="1">';
                html+='<thead>';
                html+='<tr>';
                html+='<th>NOME</th>';
                html+='<th>CATEGORIA</th>';
                html+='</tr>';
                html+='</thead>';
                html+='<tbody>';
                html+='<tr>';
                html+='<td>'+data.cliente_nome+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+data.cat_name+'</td>';
                html+='</tr>';
                html+='</tbody>';
                html+='</table>';
                $('.response').html(html);
              }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**código curl em php**

```
     <?php
    $cURL = curl_init('clientes_db.php');
    $nome = $_POST['cliente_nome'];
    echo $nome;
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($cURL);
    $post = array(
      'cliente_nome'=> $nome
    );
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $resultado = curl_exec($cURL);
    curl_close($cURL);
    ?>
```

**código que acessa o banco em php**

```
    <?php

    $nome = $_POST['cliente_nome'];

    class clientes_db
    {
      public function __construct()
      {
        mysql_connect('localhost','Admin','admin');
        mysql_select_db('avaliacao');
      }

      public function getClientes($nome)
      {
    $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_clientes WHERE cli_nome = '$nome'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    if (is_string($key))
    $fields[mysql_field_name($select, $i++)] = $value;
    }
    $cat_name = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT cat_nome FROM tbl_categorias WHERE  cat_id = '$row[cli_categoria]'"));
    $fields['cli_categoria'] = $cat_name['cat_nome'];
    $json_result = $fields;
    }
    return json_encode($json_result);
    }
    }

    $clientes = new clientes_db;
    $select   = $clientes->getClientes($_POST['cliente_nome']);

    if ($select) {
      echo$select;
    }
```

agradeço a ajuda galera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro .. É desnecessário usar o cURL sendo que você está acessando seu próprio script.. Com a requisição cURL seu site vai fazer duas requisições ao invés de uma, acarretando com isso na demora da resposta ao usuário.
No jQuery, ao invés de passar um JSON para o atributo **data** do método **ajax()** , você poderia passar o retorno do método **serialize()** que ficaria mais limpo, assim:

**Trecho do HTML**

```
$("#form1").submit(function(e) {
    var form = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "nova_busca.php",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "JSON",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success:
        // ...
```

Com isso, o arquivo php não irá mais receber o parâmetro POST["**cliente_nome**"] e sim POST["**txt_nome**"] e POST["seach"] ..
Feito isso, sem usar o cURL, vamos fazer a conexão e requisição dos dados do MySQL com o novo arquivo **nova_busca.php**.

**nova_busca.php**

```
<?php

// sua classe para conexão ao MySQL
class clientes_db {
    public function __construct() {
        mysql_connect("localhost", "Admin", "admin");
        mysql_select_db("avaliacao");
    }
    public function getClientes($nome) {
        // seleciona todos os clientes que tem o nome parecido com a pesquisa
        $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_clientes WHERE cli_nome LIKE \"%".$nome."%\"");
        // com o while, instancia todos em uma variável $fields
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
            $i = 0;
            // seleciona o nome da categoria do cliente
            $cat_name = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT cat_nome FROM tbl_categorias WHERE cat_id = "$row[cli_categoria]""));

            // instacia na variável
            $fields[$i]["cliente_nome"] = $row["cli_nome"];
            $fields[$i]["cat_name"] = $cat_name["cat_nome"];

            $i++;
        }
        // retorna string JSON
        return json_encode($fields);
    }
}

$nome = $_POST["txt_nome"];
$clientes = new clientes_db();
$select = $clientes->getClientes($nome);

// informa ao navegador que o conteúdo da página é JSON
header("Content-Type: application/json");
// imprime o JSON na página
echo $select;

?>
```

e o script ficará mais ou menos assim:

**script na tag**

```
$(function() {
    $("#form1").submit(function(e) {
        var form = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "nova_busca.php",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "JSON",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
            // alert(data.cliente_nome);
            var html = "";
            html+="<table border=\"1\">";
            html+="<thead>";
            html+="<tr>";
            html+="<th>NOME</th>";
            html+="<th>CATEGORIA</th>";
            html+="</tr>";
            html+="</thead>";
            html+="<tbody>";
            if(data.length > 0) {
                for(data as novo_data) {
                    html+="<tr>";
                    html+="<td>"+novo_data.cliente_nome+"</td>";
                    html+="<td>"+novo_data.cat_name+"</td>";
                    html+="</tr>";
                }
            } else {
                html+="<tr>";
                html+="<td colspan=\"2\">Nenhum cliente com este nome.</td>";
                html+="</tr>";
            }
            html+="</tbody>";
            html+="</table>";
            $(".response").html(html);
        }
        });
    });
});
```

Com estas funções implementadas desta forma, a pesquisa retornará as pessoas com nomes parecidos, Ex: Você tem 3 clientes cadastrados com os nomes (Diego, Diego Rodrigues, Diego Teixeira) e no campo de busca digita 'Diego' ele irá retornar os 3 cadastrados. Já se você pesquisar 'Diego T' ele irá retornar apenas um cliente.

Espero ter ajudado e espero que tenha entendido sua dúvida.. Qualquer coisa, pergunta aí ..

Comment: perfeito @Whatyson